# Ionic application for windows phone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows-phone-8, ionic-framework

I am developing app using ionic framework.I have successful developed app for android and ios.Now I am going for windows phone:
When I add platform using:

```
ionic platform add wp8
```

I got Error

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'Q'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-wp8/3.8.1/package/bin/lib/create.js:20:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
Error: /home/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-wp8/3.8.1/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

I am using ubuntu opreating system.This works for windows opreating system

Comment: first check the available platform's for your project to add as ionic platform ls

Comment: Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, ubuntu, webos

Comment: That's why it is throwing error for you ... so it is unable to add window's platform for you

Comment: if you still want's to add window's platform you have to install visual studio ...and than you have to add window's 8 templates in your visual studio

Comment: then how can I add this?

Comment: okk......................

Comment: for reference please see this [link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check the available platform's for your project to add as `ionic platform ls`